# MySQL variables (USE STATEMENT)

Tags: php, mysql, database, linux

I have set MySQL variable:

```
SET @test = 'my_db';
select @test;
```

Then

```
use  @test
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '@test'
```

OR

```
mysql> SET @test = 'my_db';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @test;
+-------+
| @test |
+-------+
| my_db   |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use @test
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '@test'
```

How I can use variable value with use USE STATEMENT in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables cannot be used as identifiers in MySQL. You're looking for macro expansion, which MySQL doesn't support.

> User variables are intended to provide data values. They cannot be used directly in an SQL statement as an identifier or as part of an identifier, such as in contexts where a table or database name is expected, or as a reserved word such as SELECT

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html

It *is* possible to work around this for some statements such as `SELECT` by using prepared statements, but you cannot prepare a `USE` statement, so it's not an option for you in this case.

You'll have to select the database in your application code by using `mysqli_select_db($test)` or by executing a query such as `mysqli_query("USE $test");`

Comment: Sure, but you're just pushing the problem out a step because you can't  do `USE @test` in a stored procedure either. The closest you can get in pure MySQL is to do do something like `CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @test, '.tablename')`, and then prepare that statement. You'll need to do that for every statement that needs to refer to the database, and deal with the logging and replication problems that come with not using `USE`.